# JS claims that 656 < 7 is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json array of structure:

```
 { data : [ { "num" : val , "time" : val } , ... ] }
```

I need to find the largest values of the num, and min/max of time, as well as to move the objects into array of tuples:

```
 [[time,num]...]
```

to do this I use to following structure(It's a success callback callback with output being the json string) :

```
        var json = $.parseJSON(output);

        var xmin = json.data[0].time ; 
        var xmax = json.data[0].time ; 
        var ymax = json.data[0].num  ;

        var data = [];

        //console.log(Math.max.apply(Math,json.data.num));

        for( i = 0 ; i < json.data.length ; i++){
            if( json.data[i].time < xmin){ 
                xmin = json.data[i].time;
            }
            if( json.data[i].time > xmax){ 
                xmax = json.data[i].time;
            }

            if(  ymax < json.data[i].num  ){ 
                console.log(ymax + " " + json.data[i].num + "b " + (ymax > json.data[i].num) );                 
                ymax = json.data[i].num ;
                console.log(ymax + " " + json.data[i].num+ "a");
            }

            data.push([json.data[i].time,json.data[i].num]);
        }
```

I get that the ymax is 7 at the end with this logget to console:

```
....
607 607a
607 646b true
646 646a
646 656b true
656 656a
656 7b true
7 7a
```

As you see it claims that 656 < 7 is true. I'm not asynchronous guru and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't shown your actual data which is the important part, however I'd guess you're comparing strings and ints/floats. use `parseInt(n, 10)` or `parseFloat(n)`

Comment: Are you sure those are numbers and not strings?

Comment: You're clearly working with strings `"656" < "7" === true`

Comment: Strings are compared character by character unless they are no equal or there aren't any characters left to compare. The first character of '656' is less than the first character of '7'. That's the reason.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari +adeneo you guys are correct. Guys asking for data didn't get the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try comparing with intval. It is possible you are comparing strings with integers. A simple javascript:alert(656 <7); in url box shows false as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to properly convert your strings to numbers before comparing:

```
var ymax = parseInt(json.data[0].num, 10);

....

var ycur = parseInt(json.data[i].num, 10);
if(  ymax < ycur  ){ 
    console.log(ymax + " " + ycur + "b " + (ymax > ycur) );                 
    ymax = ycur;
    console.log(ymax + " " + ycur + "a");
}
```

If you don't have a real need to do the comparison and are only interested in tracking the max value you can one-line it inside your loop with:

```
ymax = Math.max(ymax, parseInt(json.data[i].num, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you are comparing strings and not values. A useful shortcut for converting strings to integers is `~~`:

e.g.

```
var ymax = ~~json.data[0].num;
var ycur = ~~json.data[i].num;
if(  ymax < ycur  ){
    ...
}
```

`~~` is both shorter and faster than `parseInt`. The only downside is it is limited to typical integer max values (which are very large in practical situations).